# PHP Set Time Limit?

Tags: php, timeout

**What I'm Doing:**

I'm working on a script that needs to cycle through thousands of active orders one at a time to pull data off an external server, and then update my database with any changes.

**The Question:**

Can I add `set_time_limit(0)` to disable the timeout and allow the script to run as long as it would need? Also, if it is possible would this change the timeout of other php scripts? (I only want to disable timeout for this script).

**Note:** This script will be ran through a cron and not accessible elsewhere on my website.

Comment: Yes to the first part. No to the second part (unless these scripts are called/included inside your script).

Comment: `set_time_limit(0)` will set no limit on time to the script and all the scripts included in (called from) the script. It won't interfere with any other scripts, even the same script called without `set_time_limit(0)` in another instance.

Comment: @SergeyVidusov & bansi Thanks a lot guys. That's perfect then because it will allow the script to take as long as it needs without affecting anything else.

Comment: be careful with `set_time_limit(0)` the script can be terminated by user abort if served by web server or can be terminated by `SIGTERM` or any termination signal above it. also make sure the script will never get into some infinite loop.